# R count and substract events from a data frame

Tags: r, count

I am trying to calculate the families sizes from a data frame, which also contains two types of events : family members who died, and those who left the family. I would like to take into account these two parameters in order to compute the actual family size. 
Here is a reproductive example of my problem, with 3 families only :

```
family <- factor(rep(c("001","002","003"), c(10,8,15)), levels=c("001","002","003"), labels=c("001","002","003"), ordered=TRUE)
dead <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
left <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0)
DF <- data.frame(family, dead, left)  ; DF
```

I could count N = total family members (in each family) in a second dataframe DF2, by simply using        table()

```
DF2 <- with(DF, data.frame(table(family)))
colnames(DF2)[2] <- "N"   ; DF2
family  N
1    001 10
2    002  8
3    003 15
```

But i can not find a proper way to get the actual number of people (for example, creating a new variable N2 into DF2) , calculated by substracting to N the number of members who died or left the family. I suppose i have to relate the two dataframes DF and DF2 in a way. i have looked for other related questions in this site but could not find the right answer... 
If anyone has a good idea, it would be great !
Thank you in advance.. 
Deni

Comment: ` library(dplyr); DF %>% group_by(family) %>% summarise( n()-sum(dead)-sum(left))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic : First we want to `group_by(family)` and then calculate 2 numbers : i) total #obs in each group  ii) subtract the `sum(dead) + sum(left)` from this total .

In `dplyr` package : `n()` helps us get the total #observations in each group

In `data.table`    : `.N` does the same above job

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(family) %>% summarise( total = n(), current = n()-sum(dead,left, na.rm = TRUE))
#  family total current
#  (fctr) (int)   (dbl)
#1    001    10       6
#2    002     8       4
#3    003    15       7


library(data.table)
# setDT() is preferred if incase your data was a data.frame. else just DF.
setDT(DF)[, .(total = .N, current = .N - sum(dead, left, na.rm = TRUE)), by = family]
#   family total current
#1:    001    10       6
#2:    002     8       4
#3:    003    15       7
```

Comment: Thank you Joel for both solutions you provided. This is a big step for me, Thanks

Comment: Please don't post [code only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques) that isn't helpful to anyone except the OP with his/her specific problem

Comment: This worked fine in the example above but not in my real database, where i had to count specific attributes of certain variables (not only 0 or 1) :      "DF %>% group_by(family) %>% summarise(  total = n(), current = n()-sum(dead==1)-sum(left==1))" i got the following error message : Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  wrong result size (3853), expected 33 or 1 ... Any idea how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: @joel.wilson, you precisely pointed the issue i actually have. Indeed you should consider my database the folowing way : instead of the two binary variables (left, dead), i have one categorical variable "reason" with attributes ranging from 1 to 9 : i would like to substract entries having the attributes "1", and "3" for ex.

Comment: @joel.wilson ok here below i **try** :    `family <- factor(rep(c("001","002","003"), c(10,8,15)), levels=c("001","002","003"), labels=c("001","002","003"), ordered=TRUE)
reason<- c(9,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,6,3,3,3,3,6,4,8,1,7,7,3,1,1,9,1,4,5,3,7,6,3,1,9)`

Comment: even in this context, `sum(reason==1)+sum(reason==3)` works. I'm unsure of the error you getting. Would you mind restarting your session and loading just `dplyr`.

Comment: @joel.wilson i dont know if this is clear for you, i know it would be easier with the real database. I am not sure how to load here a subset of my databse . Thank you anyways for you help ---- All right i'll try  again ........ No, didn't work, still got this error message : `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  wrong result size (3853), expected 33 or 1`

Comment: Would be missing data  `NA` the possible reason for this error message ? i doubt it, but this is the only thing i see which could screw the result

Comment: No, NA can't be the reason. forgot to add the `na.rm=T` inside `sum()`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg would you mind helping us here? what could possibly be the cause of that error OP is having. I didn't find ny errors. Could be version difference of dplyr package?

Comment: I'm not sure. Why would OP have an error related to `mutate` if they are using `summarise`? Looks like they are not telling the whole story

Comment: @DavidArenburg @joel.wilson  i do not know either, this is the returned error message i have. I have `NA` in quite a lot of entries in the `reason`variable, but otherwise i think my comment above reflects my data pretty much.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` option

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(dl~family, transform(DF, dl = dead + left), 
      FUN = function(x) c(total=length(x), current=length(x) - sum(x))))
```

Or a modified version is

```
transform(aggregate(. ~ family, transform(DF, total = 1,
  current = dead + left)[c(1,4:5)], FUN = sum), current = total - current)
#     family total current
#1    001    10       6
#2    002     8       4
#3    003    15       7
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found another which works fine (from another post), allowing to compute everything from the original `DF` table. This uses the `ddply` function :

`DF <- ddply(DF,.(family),transform,total=length(family))
DF <- ddply(DF,.(family),transform,actual=length(family)-sum(dead=="1")-sum(left=="1"))
DF`

Thanks a lot to everyone who helped ! Deni